# When should syscall function be used instead of glibc wrapper?

Tags: linux, system-calls, glibc

[man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) page of `syscall` says, "it is useful when there is no wrapper function in c library". If wrapper function is available, Is it always better to use wrapper function ? If not, when should prefer `syscall` over it?

Comment: I cannot think of anytime that I have needed to use `syscall`. Use the wrappers.

Comment: Hi @EdHeal , my question is inspired by watching heavy use of syscall in strace tests suite. See, [this](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/tests/getrusage.c) for example.

Comment: It is testing the kernel. What has that to do with day to day usage

Comment: @EdHeal : Although, for [capget](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/tests/caps.c) test, wrapper function is used. Any reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never.

The only situation where you should *ever* consider using `syscall()` is to invoke a system call that doesn't have a wrapper in your C library. It has absolutely no advantages over a libc wrapper, and many disadvantages. (For instance: It is less clear, non-portable, and bypasses compile-time checks on the number and type of arguments.)